# Isotope - show latest post within each category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**How it works right now:**

- It shows the latest 6 projects as default
- When pressing the specific lists it shows the latest post within that category that are the latest 6 projects. E.g: It shows the 4 latest within *Foto* because 4 of the 6 are categories as *Foto*. This mean that if the 6 latest projects are in the category *Foto*, none of the posts within the other categories would show. *Please see screenshow below if you don't understand.*

[image: Does not show all posts within each category]

**How it should work:**

- Show the latest 6 projects as default (this works)
- When press one category it should show the latest 6 posts within that category

[See page here](http://goo.gl/9IsTIl)

*Note: If you are using Chrome with Windows 10 the hover effect has for some reason stopped working. The bug has been reported to Chrome and Windows*

```
<ul id="filters" class="whitetext whitelink myeluft">
    <li class="smoothtrans"><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected smoothtrans">Alle</a></li>
    <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.foto' class="smoothtrans">Foto</a></li>
    <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.video' class="smoothtrans">Video</a></li>
    <li class="smoothtrans"><a href='#' data-filter='.web' class="smoothtrans">Web</a></li>
</ul>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => (array( 'foto', 'video', 'web' )),
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'post_taxonomy' => 'any',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 


// Loop post_type
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category");  //Get the terms for this particular item
        $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
            }
        ?> 
        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-4"> 
            <ul class="grid cs-style-3">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                              the_post_thumbnail('frontpage_thumb');
                        } ?>
                        <figcaption class="lefttext">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <span class="offgrey"><?php echo(types_render_field( "produkt", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?> / <?php echo(types_render_field( "produsert", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></span>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Se prosjekt" rel="bookmark" class="smoothtrans">Se prosjekt</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>             
        </div> <!-- end item -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/toucheffects.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
    $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
        itemSelector : '.item', 
        layoutMode : 'masonry'
    });

    //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
    var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
    $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
     var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

    return false;
    });

});
```

**My thoughs (updated 13/07/15)**

I have looked more into it, and when disabling the `'posts_per_page'` and just using the custom wp settings, the problem is the same. So I guess that the problem is that when pressing each category it does not refresh or get any other posts than first shown.

I therefore believe that the args must be set another place, or the js must be modified to get newest posts. But this is not my expertise, and therefore I ask you if you have any solution. I have searched on both search engines and SO for this question, but I couldn't find it. However, I see that similar pages have the same problem. With that I believe that solving this problem would help other users aswell.

Comment: I take it in the php section the opening php tag ( at the very top ) is actually there and you just missed putting it in the question?

Comment: Good question. I will check it out when I ger back. But I believe so, else it wouldn't have worked?

Comment: yet it doesn't work, or you wouldn't be here, as you are mixing html and php code it's possible it got output to the page and not executed as code.

Comment: I have the opening php tag at the beginning of the page. So you believe that the code is correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say I believe that, that was just the most obvious thing.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, after enabling wp_debug I get an error. You can take a look at it if you want. The question has been updated :)

Comment: that means the value of this $post_taxonomy is not set or defined yet

Comment: I have looked more into it, and when disabling the `'posts_per_page'` and just using the custom wp settings, the problem is the same. So I guess that the problem is that when pressing each category it does not refresh or get any other posts than first shown. Or what do you think?

Comment: There are a few parts to this Q. One is fetching the correct info from the server (php). You are only fetching the last 6 posts, you want to run seperate queries to get 6 of each and combine the results (posts). You will of course have 18 posts to show on the page, if you want 6 only you will need to hide the other 12 with css. There are better ways but this will get you started.

Answer (score 5):

Your current code ask to the database for 6 recent posts only. Isotope plugin then filter them on the frontend.

This means that it can't show more post apart from this 6. When you click on the tags (foto, video, web) isotope filter this 6 posts to show only the ones that have the selected category. It doesn't ask for any more posts, it only filter the posts you already have.

You can make your code ask for more posts when you click on the filter tags, but you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Been looking a little bit into AJAX, but I am not so familiar with this either. Do you have a resource to refer to, or some code?

Comment: Did you finally make this work? Please, if my answer helped you, mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Two Things I don't understand

1. Why their are two navigation/choice [image: Two nav]

2.First one work correct but second does not have any link or function it has link to just back to same using # hyper reference.

3.video and web have same thing did you put it knowingly if not check assigned category

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am working on the website, and it has not yet been launched. Meaning there are several bugs and not updated posts /pages. Please only look at the front page (http://goo.gl/9IsTIl). The filtering works, - I have simply not posted correct and updated posts within video & web. When this question is solved, I am going to fix all the other pages and posts.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is fetch all the posts at once and show only 6 using something like this

```
jQuery('#isotope-list').isotope({
    filter: ':nth-child(-n+3)'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Tried your tip by using `1n+4`, but didn't worked. It worked for "all", but not for the categories. The problem was still the same...

Answer (score 0):

**Filter will work only on available items on page.**

When pressing one category it should show the latest 6 posts within that category **if available**, in your case (http://www.vekvemedia.no/) total item are 6 and 5 item belongs to "foto" category so when pressing "foto" category it will show 5 items.

**Solution-1**: if you have "All" option then you have to load all the available items in first load after that filter will work and show all the items of matching category.

**Solution-2**: By using ajax, fetch 6 records that match category(like "foto")

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the solution 1 is something I already have on the the "Portfolio"-page. I will check AJAX out, but never been in touch with it before, hehe.